# Mass irretrievable deletion of text

Tags: microsoft-word

Now and then if I am typing rapidly in Word, I press some key or combination of keys that deletes a large body of as yet unsaved text - and, I think, automatically saved text at times - that cannot be retrieved even by using the undo function. This outrages me for obvious reasons. What might it be that I am doing?

Comment: You haven't told us which program you're using, or even which OS, so there's absolutely no way anybody can even begin to answer your question.

Comment: Have you tried <CRTL><Z> ?   I know that works for me in my apps, and that its pretty standard across Unix and Windows systems, but I'm unaware how that differs from the "undo function", if indeed it does.

Comment: I am just using Word. What happens is I am typing along and the entire text of the document vanishes. Perhaps I have typed one key beyond which the action cannot be undone as, so far as I know, you can only undo the immediate past action. If I close without saving I sometimes get back a few lines when I reopen. I will try control Z next time.

Comment: In Word you should be able to undo a large number of changes, you need to keep a close eye on what extraneous keys you are hitting. As an example if you accidentally hit the Alt key you will end up in the menu system where you could end up closing your current document and cancelling the save... Make sure you look at your screen regularly and save regularly.

Answer (score 1):

There are numerous ways to achieve this

- `Shift + PageUp` or `Shift + PageDown` then `Backspace` or `Delete` or any character to be honest
- `Ctrl + Shift + Home` or `Ctrl + Shift + End` then `Backspace` or `Delete` or any character to be honest